# Inject services in React Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Consider the following scenario:

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Api
{
  constructor () {
    this.state = {
      token: null,
      endpoint: process.env.REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT
    };
  }

  request (method, data, uri, headers) {
    uri = uri.replace(/^\//, '');

    return axios({
      method: method,
      url: this.state.endpoint + "/" + uri,
      data: data,
      headers: Object.assign({}, headers, { Authorization: "Bearer TESET TOKEN" })
    });
  }
}

export default Api;
```

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import LocaleStringsService from '../Services/LocaleStringsService.js';
import LocaleStringsList from '../Components/LocaleStringsList.js';

class Translate extends Component
{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            strings: []
        }

        this.stringsService = new LocaleStringsService();
    }

  [...]

  render () {
      return (
         <LocaleStringsList updater={this.stringsService.bulk} locale={this.props.match.params.locale} strings={this.state.strings} />
      );
  }
}

export default Translate;
```

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import LocaleStringsListItem from './LocaleStringsListItem.js';

class LocaleStringsList extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);

    [...]

    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);

    [...]
  }

  onSubmit (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.updater(this.props.locale, this.props.strings);
  }

  [...]

  render () {
    [...]

    return (
      <form onSubmit={that.onSubmit} [...]>
        [...]
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default LocaleStringsList;
```

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import LocaleString from '../Entities/LocaleString.js';
import Api from '../Services/Api.js';

class LocaleStringsService extends Component
{
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);

    this.api = new Api();
  }

  [...]

  bulk (locale, locales) {
    let data = [];

    [...]

    return this.api.request('PATCH', data, '/locales/' + locale + '/strings', {})
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      });
  }
}

export default LocaleStringsService;
```

This is the error:

```
LocaleStringsService.js TypeError: Cannot read property 'request' of undefined
```

There is definitely some issues with scope and the usage of `this` while passing the function.

I have attempted to use the Context API however failing miserably.

How do I do this properly?

Comment: Any other errors like, "cannot read env of undefined"?

Comment: @deostroll None.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try arrow function syntax inside class (function as class property)

```
class LocaleStringsService extends Component
{
  // Attention to the syntax - Arrow Function as Class Property
  bulk = (locale, locales) => {
    //Todo
  }
}

export default LocaleStringsService;
```

Ref: (Here you'll find 5 way to bind `this`. I've shown you the way number 5 which I prefer personally) https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56

Comment: How is this different from what I am doing?

Comment: Look at the `bulk`. It is not method actually. It is *Arrow Function in Class Property*

Comment: This also worked, awesome! What's the difference between your method and @adz5A?

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the solution as it's the method I've used, however @adz5A's is also valid!

Comment: Actually, this `this` is not related to react. It is JavaScript. `this` behavior is depends on the context at runtime. In the way to `bind`, you're telling to JavaScript explicitly what should be the context of `this`.

Comment: I would also point out that this is not part of the language yet, but is still a state-3 proposal. This means that you are relying on code transpilation atm, subject to bugs and which might not behave like the final browser implementation and is subject to change (especially regarding the final ASI behaviour).

Comment: Yes, it is true that this feature is under stage-3. But I don't think so, If you see the transpiled code, this is nothing but `this.bulk = (...) => {...}` inside of the `contractor`. I believe this is why react team include this `preset`  on their `Create-React-App` by default. They also recommend this syntax as it is much cleaner and readable - even who don't know much deep of `JavaScript` they can also understand this.

Comment: That's a good point, mine is that it should be very explicit in SO answers as they are often used as docs for the language and/or the framework. For a react users whom only uses transforms for jsx (or may be using TS) it could be confusing, and he would need to look at the comment to understand why it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

The `api` field is undefined because the `this` is not bound to the value you expect within the body of the `bulk` method. Try passing it as

```
render () {
      return (
         <LocaleStringsList updater={rhis.stringsService.bulk.bind(this.stringsService)} locale={this.props.match.params.locale} strings={this.state.strings} />
      );
}
```

Comment: This worked, awesome! But is this the React.js way of doing things?

Comment: In react, you usually tend to pass around props that can be used `as is`, the error you have is because the function you passed around needs some context to be run properly (hence the `this` issue), as a rule of thumb you should prefer using plain functions which does not rely on `this`, or for difficult cases HOC: https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html

Comment: For further reading on the issue you encountered I would suggest reading https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md , imo one of the best breakdowns of this particular feature of the language.

Answer (score -1):

I don't where the scope problem is but you do not need to model your API module using a class. Normal functions would do -

```
import axios from 'axios';

const token = null
const endpoint = process.env.REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT

export function request(method, data, uri, headers) {
    uri = uri.replace(/^\//, '');

    return axios({
      method: method,
      url: endpoint + "/" + uri,
      data: data,
      headers: Object.assign({}, headers, { Authorization: "Bearer TESET TOKEN" })
    });
}
```

Making that change to the module gives you two advantages -

1. Anyone using the request function do not need to to create a new instance of the API class
2. No `this` scope problems. It's not relevant in this case anyways.

Comment: I need it to remain as a class because in the future I need to implement an authentication layer ontop of it using another service.